# How to get the output of another program as pipe to my program?

Tags: c, bash

For e.g i have the following program in windows.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *input = argv[1];
    printf("your input: %s", input);
    return 0;
}
```

When i run a cmd shell and invoke

```
C:\>whoami | main.exe
```

i get as output

```
your input: (null)
```

The first argument `argv[0]` (the filename itself) is passed correct. How to receive the output of `whoami` as input to my program?

**Edit**: Since people mostly ask for code if you ask a question, i will also provide code in my answer. Just to be fair. The solution i use (thanks to Gerardo Zinno) is to read from stdin - so i use `scanf`.

```
char input[1024] = {0};
read(STDIN_FILENO, input, 1024);
input[strcspn(input, "\n")] = '\0';
printf("you wrote: %s", input);
return 0;
```

Comment: Read from `stdin`

Comment: Your program will probably work if you run it like this `main.exe $(whoami)`

Comment: `$(whoami)` wont work in windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to read from the `stdin` just like if the input was coming from a user typing in the terminal. The pipe will send (link) the `stdout` of `whoami` to the `stdin` of your program.

There are many options to read from the stdin. You can use `fread` with `stdin` as last parameter, `scanf`, `fscanf(stdin,...)`,...